# Angular error creating an angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Whenever I try to create an angular project using `ng new my-app-name`, it shows the following error!

`C:\Users\HP>ng new my-app-name`

I get the following error in red marker!

> Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist. 
>   Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.

I am using Angular CLI: 1.5.5
Node: 8.9.1
Windows: win32 x64

I can't post the image since i am new to stackoverflow and have not reached the required reputation to post the picture!

Thank You!

Comment: You get this error where? When doing what? We can't see your screen.

Comment: @JBNizet after I enter the command to create a new angular app inside my directory C:\Users\HP>
The error is stated above as I mentioned.
Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist. Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
It was on the command prompt

Comment: First of all, you should create a folder called Angular_Projects or something to the effect and create your projects inside of that dir. Also, try starting Command Prompt as Administrator. You may not have "write" access to the folder you're trying to write to.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I created a folder to create my projects inside of that folder but still i am facing the same problem. However, if i run cmd as admin i can create it. Is there any way i can create the app in the folder i just created because i just want my system32 folder to be untouched! And yes i do have a write permission as well.

Comment: @JBNizet I can't post a picture sir. I have not reached the required amount of reputation to post it.

Comment: But you can (and should) post text. And what you get in your console window is text. Just use copy/paste.

Comment: @JBNizet
After entering folowing command
`C:\Users\HP>ng new my-app-name`

I get the following error
>Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist. Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.

Comment: Start a cmd prompt as admin and use the "cd" command to get to your desired folder. For example "cd C:\Users\HP\Angular_Projects"

Comment: You may also SHIFT + Right Click on a folder and click "Open Command Window Here" which will start an admin cmd prompt already in that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the problem was folder permission. I tried in a folder with full permission and worked.

If you are using windows just uncheck Readonly

If you are using OS base on Linux Kernel just:

sudo chmod 644 -R foldername

Comment: i had this problem solved. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

On ng new myapp.This error occurs..!?

Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.